# Using Xcode project in react native plugin causes header file not found errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm developing a react native plugin (iOS) that uses another project as depencency. Building the project on its own, no errors occur. When I build a react native app with my plugin inside, I get the error that some header files are not found in my plugin.

My structure

- MyReactNativeApp

  - node_modules

    - myPlugin

      - iOS

        - myPlugin.xcodeproj
        - folder1

          - myProject1.xcodeproj
          - folder2

            - myProject2.xcodeproj
            - folder3

              - file1.h
            - folder4

              - file2.h

myProject2 has some header files defined that reference to each other.

When I build myProject1.xcodeproj, there are no errors. When I build myPlugin, the header files can't include each other.

The header search paths are set. This shouldn't be the problem.

Does someone may has an idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution for this problem, but one for my actual problem that .framework modules couldn't be found. Due to this error I tried to add the project directly.

If a .framework module could not be found, you need to add this to your .podspec file of myPlugin

```
 s.vendored_frameworks = 'ios/Frameworks/myProject1.framework', 'ios/Frameworks/myProject2.framework'
 s.public_header_files = 'ios/Frameworks/myProject1.framework/**/*.h'
```

Maybe only the `s.public_header_files` will fix the error in the question.